# Why do I get the unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR on my server, however on xampp it works fine?

Tags: php

I have really simple php code:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
echo (new DateTime())->format('r');
?>
```

and when I run it locally (thanks to xampp) it works fine and shows me the time:

```
Tue, 29 Sep 2015 11:41:35 -0400
```

but when I put it on my hosting webserver, I get the message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ',' or ';' in (...)/public_html/test/timeoftheserver.php on line 3
```

what might be the issue?

Comment: Support for this syntax was added in PHP 5.4.0 `Added class member access on instantiation (e.g. (new foo)->bar()) support.`.... is PHP 5.4 is now EOL and only supported for security fixes, you really should be pushing your hosting to update to a supported version of PHP

Comment: Many hosting providers offer this as an option, somewhere in your hosting account settings you can likely choose your PHP version, make sure it is >= 5.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect one is a lower version of PHP. This should work on either:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); 
$d = new DateTime();
echo $d->format('r');
?>
```